# A cosmological integral.

Tags: integration

This integral comes from the standard cosmological model.
$$
t(z)=\frac{1}{H_0}\int_z^\infty \frac{dy}{(1+y)\sqrt{(1-m)(1+y^3)+m}}
$$
and gives the cosmological time at redshift $z$.

It seems that it has an exact solution:
 $$
 t(z)=\frac{2}{3H_0\sqrt{m}}\sinh^{-1}\left( \sqrt{\frac{m}{(1-m)(1+z)^3}}\right)
 $$
I've tempted to prove this result, but I don't see a good substitution. Someone can gives me an hint?

Comment: I would first try $(1-m)y^3=\sinh^2 t$...

Comment: My numerical experiments strongly disagree with ur above conjecture...

Comment: Example: for $m=0,z=0$ your formula for yields $t_0(0)=2/3$ but numerical integration suggests $t_0(0)\approx 0.6431$. Note that i have set the overall constant to one

Answer (score 0):

(Perhaps not what you expect as a solution...)
Let $t_1(z)$ pour original expression, and $t_2(z)$ what you expect to be the closed formula. Write $t_1(z)=\int_z^{+\infty}f(y)dy$, then the derivative of $t_1(z)$ is $-f(z)$. Compute also the derivative of $t_2$. If you find that the two derivatives are equal, the remark that $t_1$ and $t_2$ goes to $0$ as $z\to +\infty$ show that $t_1=t_2$.